# arch linux hdmi not detected

Tags: arch-linux, monitoring

today I started my laptop, but my external display was not working. I ran the command `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1280x720      59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, there is no hdmi. When I run this exact same command on my **other** computer, it shows this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1280x720      59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00 
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

my os: `Linux acer-a515 5.7.12-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri, 31 Jul 2020 17:38:22 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm having the same issue after updating to linux 5.7.12

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. No HDMI output on Linux and Windows installation after a full system upgrade on Linux.

It turned out the latest version of GRUB (version 2.04-8) interferes with the HDMI ports on some laptops, so you need to boot into Linux and downgrade it back to 2.04-7 or lower.

On Arch, you can load the old package from the pacman cache:

```bsh
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
sudo pacman -U grub-2:2.04-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```